# SQL Aggregation prior to advanced SQL

Tags: sql, pivot

Given a simple case like this:

```
Gender DeptID
--------------
M        1
F        1
M        2
F        2 
F        2
```

What SQL statement I need to write If I want to generate the following result using SQL without using advanced CUBE, Rollup, etc., just using plain SQL-92:

```
GenderSum Dept1Sum Dept2Sum
----------------------------
M           1         1
F           1         2
```

I was wondering how such information would be generated by ETL in the past using SQL?

Remark: It is possible to use Group by on gender and union that with a group by on DetptId to get a vertical result set but this is clearly not what I want.

Comment: So you are asking for a simple query?

Comment: A query of any complexity will do :)

Comment: Which version of SQL are you using?

Comment: Any version of any db will do. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try the following pivot query:

```
SELECT Gender AS GenderSum,
       SUM(CASE WHEN DeptID = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Dept1Sum,
       SUM(CASE WHEN DeptID = 2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Dept2Sum
FROM yourTable
GROUP BY Gender
```